# ¿Por qué no puedo leer archivo JSON en JS?

Tags: php, ajax, json, javascript

Traté de alguna forma "conectar" un archivo de JS  con uno PHP , debido a que preciso de unas consultas en BD.

La conexión la hice por medio de AJAX. Desde JS le envío el id de una "entidad" a php por medio de un GET. Luego devuelvo de PHP a JS un archivo JSON que contiene un objeto con los atributos descritos en el código.

El problema es que al leer el archivo JSON en JS, por medio de un *dataJson.ID_SI* por ejemplo, no me da ningun error, pero toma el valor del atributo como

> undefined

Cabe decir que cuando imprimo un **alert(dataJson)** en JS, muestra correctamente en pantalla todos los datos, quizas no este accediendo de forma correcta a los atributos. Adjunto el código de ambos archivos (JS y PHP)

**infoAction.php**

```
<?php
  include 'sitioTuristico.php';

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sitio = new sitioTuristico($id);
    if($sitio->getID_SI()=="INEX"){
      print "INEXISTENTE";
      exit;
    }
    $response = new stdClass();

    $response->ID_SI = $sitio->getID_SI();
    $response->URL = $sitio->getURLS();
    $response->Nombre = $sitio->getNombre();
    $response->Descripcion = $sitio->getDescripcion();
    $response->Promedio_nota = $sitio->getPromedio_Nota();
    $response->Nombre_Cat = $sitio->getNombre_Cat();
    $response->Nombre_Ciu = $sitio->getNombre_Ciu();

    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

**info.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //Solicita consulta y recibe los datos
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/infoAction.php",
    data: { id:loadData() },
    async: true,
    success: function(datos){
        var dataJson = datos;

        //Cambio de atributos de imágenes
        alert(dataJson.ID_SI); //Esto da error (undefined) 
        alert(dataJson);  //Esto muestra correctamente todos los valores
        $('img[name=imagenPrincipal]').attr("id",dataJson.ID_SI);
     });
```

Comment: te sale un error en la consola?

Comment: intenta con var dataJson = $.parseJSON(datos);

Answer (score 3):

@Spines porque usas eval ? el error debe darse porque no escapas el valor html de la url que traes desde la clase sitioTuristico. Por lo tanto si el ve un codigo html lo va a tomar como un intento de xss, tal vez por eso es el error.

Ahora no enitendo para usas un array, simplemente declara un objeto:

```
<?php
    $response = new \stdClass();
    $response->ID_SI = $sitio->getID_SI();
    header('Content-Type: application/json'); //opcion 1
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Solicita consulta y recibe los datos
   $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "php/infoAction.php",
   data: { id:"SI01" },
   async: true,
   success: function(datos){
      var dataJson = datos;

      //Cambio de atributos de imágenes
      $('img[name=imagenPrincipal]').attr("id",dataJson.ID_SI);

   },
    error: function (obj, error, objError){
      alert("Ha ocurrido un error al consultar los datos");
   },
   dataType: 'json' //opcion 2
});
```

Espero te sirva, comenta mas del problema

Comment: como soluciona tu respuesta: `indice no definido` ?

Comment: te sale indice no definido? acabo de editar la respuesta con "echo" eso deberia pasar el plain text en json

Comment: `indice no definido` =  `Notice: Undefined index:..` es un error parte de PHP

Comment: ok no habi visto esa anotacion @aldanu

Comment: El error esta por la url que pasan en el javascript. esa ruta esta conectada con la pagina actual. lo mejor es dar la ruta completa o el dominio completo.

Comment: Si por ejemplo la url en ques e esta ejecutando el js es dominio.com/test/index.html en este caso el script buscará la ruta dominio.com/test/php/infoAction.php. Es probable que el script esté en dominio.com/php/infoAction.php y por eso da el error. para poder acceder a una ruta relativa con el dominio debes agregar el slash al inicio, en el ejemplo seria /php/infoAction.php. Si esto no funciona si sugiero el url completo.

Comment: por eso mismo le he preguntado: si le sale un error en la consola...

Comment: Logré recibir correctamente el **id** en php, y claro era un error de rutas. Ahora sigo teniendo el segundo problema, cuando intento enviar el archivo JSON desde php a JS en el archivo de este, arroja un error en la función **eval()**, junto con este mensaje **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string at Object.success** en linea 9

Comment: @Alejandro Giraldo claro, es innecesario el arreglo y el eval, pero aún así tengo errores en el archivo JS, ahora en la linea 12 del código que sugeriste, **dataJson.ID_SI** lo reconoce como **undefined**

Comment: @Spines y que te imprime si solo sacas el console.log(dataJson) ?

Comment: @Alejandro Giraldo, se me habia olvidado mencionar ese pequeño gran detalle, pero cuando hago un alert(dataJson), se muestran todos los datos de forma correcta.

Comment: @Spines bueno si ese es el problema tienes dos opciones :

Comment: @Spines acabo de editar mi codigo para que las pruebes

Comment: @Alejandro Giraldo, al incluir la primera opción, sigue con el mismo problema. Con la opción 2 al devolver el objeto de PHP de JS no entra a la función success() de AJAX, sino que a error()

Comment: @Spines lo unico que se me ocurre es que le hagas strigify a la cadena devuelta (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify). seria algo como datos = JSON.stringify(response)

Comment: @Alejandro Giraldo, no me funciona el `JSON.stringify()`. Pero, probé con `$.parseJSON()` y funcionoo!!!, aunque no logro entender porque resultó con esa función y no con `JSON.parse()` ni `JSON.stringify()`. De todas formas, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para encontrar rapidamente el error, si estas vizualizando tu proyecto en apache digamos `http://localhost:8080/miproyecto/php/infoAction.php` puedes trata de pasarle manualmente el parametro `http://localhost:8080/miproyecto/php/infoAction.php?id=SI01`

pega eso en tu url y en tu infoAction.php hacele un `var_dump($_GET)` y checa si esta disponible en el **$_GET** y mira si va correcto el **key (id)**.

Esto es en caso que quieras hacerle un debug a tu aplicacion. Saludos

Comment: y si miras en la consola si tienes algún error? 404?

Comment: Si es un 404 es porque la ruta esta incorrecta por ende no la esta encontrando. Se debe verificar que la ruta a donde estas haciendo el request sea correcta.

Answer (score -1):

El array lo defines mal, hazlo de esta forma:

```
$arr = [];
$arr[] = [
// array
]
```

Comment: No veo qué tiene de mal definirlo como lo está haciendo el autor. Si conviene otra forma, es otro tema, pero `$arr[] = Array(`...`)` [es totalmente válido](http://rextester.com/TYQYGU15037).

Comment: Lo he definido en otras oportunidades como lo menciona @Mariano y no he tenido problemas al trabajar con el, de todas formas gracias por tu respuesta!.